# Null-Valued Expression Error in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to uninstall a Program via Power Shell but I am getting an error "You cannot call a method on a null valued expression.

```
PS C:\Users\user> $App = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "CVF_x64"}
PS C:\Users\user> $App.Uninstall()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $App.Uninstall()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The program is in Programs and Features on control panel, see attached picture below.
[List of Apps on Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO1ep.png)

[Powershell List of Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF6T1.png)
CVF Doesn't show up in Powershell for some reason

Comment: Did you make sure that `$App` has something in it?

Comment: Could you list the items before filtering it with where. I wonder what have you got in there. I think you are getting null at the end

Comment: Just Updated it with the images, Powershell list of apps and list of apps on control panel, idk why it doesn't show CVF in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

looks like your query does not find anything -> empty variable?

```
$x = $null
$x.uninstall()
result: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

btw. wmi is a thing of the past, use the cim cmdlets, and do the filtering one step earlier:

```
$name = "MyApp"
get-ciminstance -query "select * from win32_product where name = '$name'"
```

To identify what the value of the variable name must be simply output this beforehand and identify the exact string:

```
(get-ciminstance -query "select * from win32_product").name
```

You could also check the registry:

HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" -Name DisplayName,DisplayVersion,InstallSource,Publisher,UninstallString
```

Execute the command in the attribute UninStallString...